# Hide selected options on from other select elements

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

Given the following HTML:

```
<select name="question_order[]" id="data1">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="question_order[]" id="data2">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="question_order[]" id="data3">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

How can I hide/remove the selected options in data3, if it's already selected in data1 and data2?

For example, if I select 1 in data1, then 2 in data2, how can I remove those two option on data3?

Comment: typical an assignment `Given the following html` we would much appreciate if you can show us what you have started

Comment: check chained Select jQuery plugin, it may give your idea. [link](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aZPdd/

```
$('#data1').on('change', function() {
    var val=this.value;
   $("#data3").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
 });

$('#data2').on('change', function() {
     var val=this.value;
  $("#data3").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
});

$('#data3').on('change', function() {

});
```

Comment: Could have at least waited till this morning to make them sweat thinking they would have to turn in their own work...