# jquery how to remove option on select when it is already exist on other option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the specific option on the other select if it is already selected from other select. And also, the number of select depends on the user. And I want it to also work on change event.

```js
var a = 1;
$('#add').click(function () {
    var cnt = $('#append').val();
    for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        a++;
        $('#contain').append('<select class="sel" name="' + a + '"></select><button id="remove" name="' + a + '">x</button><br name="' + a + '"/>');
    }
    var selval = $('#contain select').val();
    var optarr = [];
    $('#contain #sel1 option').each(function () {
        var opt = $(this).val();
        if (opt != selval && opt != 'null') {
            optarr.push(opt);
        }
    });
    var optjoin = optarr.join(',');
    var optlen = optarr.length;
    var optsplit = optjoin.split(',');
    for (var x = 0; x < optlen; x++) {
        var optappend = '<option value="' + optsplit[x] + '">' + optsplit[x]+'</option>';
        $('#contain select.sel[name="'+a+'"]').append(optappend);
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '#contain #remove', function () {
    $('#contain select.sel, #contain #remove, #contain br').remove('[name="' + a + '"]');
    a--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='append' value='1' />
<button id='add'>+</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='contain'>
    <select id='sel1' class='sel1'>
        <option value='val1'>val1</option>
        <option value='val2'>val2</option>
        <option value='val3'>val3</option>
        <option value='val4'>val4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wtgt4be9/6/)**!!! It gives you some idea!! :)

Comment: Possibly you are looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649440/hide-selected-options-on-multiple-select

Comment: I'm not sure about that since that the number of `<select>` depends on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var cnt = parseInt($('#append').val());` instead of `var cnt = $('#append').val();`

complete code in progress...

intermediate result: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/b67x25tL/)

Comment: sorry dude but your answer is irrelevant to what I want. My code above was just a sample code that I created to relate to my problem and to make it short and clear to others. and also the `var cnt` is already filtered on my actual code and the user cannot enter any alpha characters.

Comment: I really don't know what should happened in your fiddle since that nothing happened even though I already selected the value and still the selected option exist on other `<select>`.

Comment: you just have to put the logic for removing the options in the `handleChange()`...